# HttpWatch Professional not showing up in Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, httpwatch

I would like to know, is there any way to have the plugin shown in Firefox? I've downloaded the latest version of HttpWatch Professional and it doesn't show up in Firefox. However, it only shows up in IE 11. I'm using Firefox 36 and Httpwatch 10.

I have:

1. Followed the troubleshooting guide posted on Httpwatch but I still can't fix the problem
2. Checked and enabled the plugin in Tools>add-ons also and still nothing
3. Reinstalled httpwatch and restarted firefox. Nothing.

I don't know what else to do. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: It should be present and enabled in both the Extensions and Plugins list in Firefox. Do you see it in both lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

1. Close Firefox and check there are no instances of firefox.exe
   running in Task Manager
2. Uninstall HttpWatch
3. Open Firefox and confirm there are no HttpWatch entries under
   Extensions or Plugins in Add-Ons
4. Close Firefox
5. Reinstall HttpWatch

Comment: Does it still have a plugin for Firefox ?

Comment: HttpWatch no longer supports Firefox - https://blog.httpwatch.com/2015/08/12/httpwatch-will-not-support-firefox-41/